# How does measurement calibration work?

Tags: programming, qiskit, error-correction, ibm-q-experience

One of the possible ways to improve the results of an experiment on the IBM machine using the Qiskit language is to use the measurement calibration methods. [This](https://qiskit.org/documentation/ignis/measurement_calibration.html) is the link to the documentation.

I understood that the calibration matrix is made looking at when a qubit in a determined state is measured in one other state. But I didn't get how this calibration matrix is applied to the results to obtain the mitigated results.

This is the command used:
`mitigated_results = meas_filter.apply(my_results, method)`.

Comment: Are you looking for a more technical answer, like what the code specifically does? Or a more conceptual answer, like what the broad procedure is to normally mitigate these errors?

Comment: The conceptual answer should be good enough, after that I can study the code myself. But it should be fine if it could be a little more specific of the description in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the question. I'll see if I can get you an answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are two methods, when you look at the code you'll see their names: pseudo_inverse and least_squares (https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-ignis/blob/master/qiskit/ignis/mitigation/measurement/filters.py). pseudo_inverse is the simpler one, it applies the inverse of the calibration matrix on the measurement results. However it has some issues, which require the usage of the least_squares method, which finds valid mitigated results, such that:
$$\text{min}_{P_{\rho}} ||\tilde{P}_{\rho}-\mathbf{A}\cdot P_{\rho}||$$
where $\mathbf{A}$ is the calibration matrix and $\tilde{P}_{\rho}$ are the measurement results. Please see more details in the last section of https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/master/community/ignis/measurement_error_mitigation.ipynb. In particular about the issues related to the pseudo inverse.

Comment: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/master/community/ignis/measurement_error_mitigation.ipynb is a broken link.